# Polymer input autocomplete

Tags: javascript, input, polymer

Based on (paper-) input I would like to call a WebSocket (not Ajax XHTMLRequest) to display different Javascript objects returned from that WS. A sensible requirement would be not to fire a request after every keypress, but

- only after a minimum of characters or a certain pattern is met;
- only after some time (~250ms?) of inactivity

How might a sketch of such an element look like?

(Is there an element for a start?)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could look at the [Vaadin combo box.](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-combo-box/vaadin-combo-box-overview.html)

It's free, and I think it has the basic capabilities you are looking for. It emmits certain events that you can utilize with some timers to fire WS requests as needed.